# What is the best way to tokenize bash shell command in PHP?

Tags: php, bash, shell, tokenize

I am in a situation where I need to take a (potentially) multi-string bash command and squash it into one string that doesn't contain any newline or carriage return characters (yet produces the same result, i.e. command semantics must not be affected).

Below are a few examples of inputs and corresponding expected outputs.

INPUT:

```sh
echo A
echo B
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```sh
echo A;echo B
```

---

INPUT

```sh
echo "continued
string"
echo "other"
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```sh
echo "continued"$'\n'"string";echo "other"
```

---

INPUT

```sh
cat file1 \
file2 \
file3
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```sh
cat file1 file2 file3
```

---

INPUT

```sh
for f in `pwd`/*
do
{ echo A; echo B
echo C; echo D; }
done
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```sh
for f in `pwd`/*; do { echo A; echo B; echo C; echo D; }; done
```

And so on. Obviously I cannot just

```php
preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ';', $input);
```

because shell supports compound commands and command lists, multiline strings, multiline command continuation operator ('\') and many more. Seems like I have no other way but to tokenize the input command and go from there. My bash knowledge is mediocre so there may be cases that I missed and they need to be handled by the solution as well.

Is there an existing PHP library or package (I have searched packagist to no avail) that would help me get closer to my goal? If no, how would you approach this challenge (no need to write code, just point a finger in a right direction).

As a desperate fallback I'll have to resort to porting the bash source code itself, but I really hope that someone will suggest a shortcut.

Comment: Interesting project. Can you clarify the motivation for packing the script into a single line. Can you encode the new lines, and decode it when sending it to bash to executed ?

Comment: @dash-o I'm essentially sending the command to the interactive shell created by phpseclib. After the command has been written to the stream, I read the packets that come back, waiting for the command prompt. If I send multiple commands on multiple lines, the response will most likely contain multiple prompts (one per input command) and I incur the risk of not understanding when it's safe to continue interaction. However, if I send multiple commands in one line (cmd1;cmd2;cmd3) I can safely expect only one prompt back and as soon as I detect it, my program can continue.

Comment: If the man reason for a king the command is identify when command is completed by detecting the promotion, consider appending, consider sending the commands as is, then add ‘echo EEENNNDDD’. Your code can wait for the EEENNNDDD to detect end of execution.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. I'll add it to my set of options to consider!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to create a parser for bash is very ambitious (and ambiguous) project . Bash is constantly evolving, and in certain areas, push the boundary beyond the POSIX standard. Consider scaling down the project - may be target the Posix shell (which will cover many shell variant: dash, ash, ...).

Consider starting with https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ It identifies few quoting options. If you implement those carefully, your approach (replacing end-of-lines with ';' may work).

Another alternative will be to start with bash syntax highlighter, for example the vim highlighter. (/usr/share/vim/vimNN/syntax/sh.vim, where NN is vim version).

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely go through the "Shell Command Language" chapter as it will be useful for my purpose. As for the vim syntax highlighter, mine only contains "llvm", "nginx" and "tablegen" files, but thanks for the direction, I'll search for the sh highlighter if forced to.